# In mobile devices' safari, <a href="#" onclick="return false"> doesn't work, why?

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, onclick, preventdefault

In moblie devices' safari, like iphone or ipad, `<a href="#" onclick="return false">` doesn't prevent default behaviour, the page was still redirected to '#', why...?
Like these html code:

```
<div style="height:1000px; width:100px"></div>
<br />    
<a href="#" onclick="return false">click me</a>
```

When click in moblie devices' safari, it goes back to the top of the page...

Comment: onclick="javascript:return false;"   ?

Comment: did you check how things work on a desktop browser? I assume it has something to do with touch vs. mouse events.

Comment: Instead of "onclick" you can give a try to "onkeyup", "onmouseup" or "onkeypress"

Comment: @adali — Why would adding a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) help? There is no loop to break or continue from.

Comment: @Tobi, keyup, mouseup would be weird...

Comment: @Kai, it works well on desktop browser. touch or mouse events would trigger a link redirection? I don't understand...

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I think mobile safari fires more than onClick on a tap. So if the href reacts on one of these and they're fired before onClick or if onClick isn't fired at all on a single tap, the redirect will still be executed. Maybe you should test with onMouseover, onMouseout etc.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. It turns out that it is a bug in the iOS 5 version of Safari. Doesn't happen in newer or older versions, or any other browser or platform.

I resolved it by adding `preventDefault` to the onclick event handler, in addition to the existing `return false`, like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); return false;">click me</a>
```

Not ideal, but it does solve the problem.

Comment: In my case there was no need for the ="..." just the "onclick" served its purpose

Answer (score 2):

I just kinda had the same problem with my links not working right on my friend's iPhone. I deleted the  `href="#"` from mine and the buttons work perfectly fine, except I have my buttons set up a little differently than you with the JavaScript.

The way I have it set up is like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var buttons=$('#button01,#button02,#button03,#button04,#button05');

buttons.click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('off-class').addClass('on-class');
        buttons.not(this).removeClass('on-class').addClass('off-class');


})
```

Then I trigger the frames I want to pop up with

```
if ($('#button01').hasClass('on-class')){
                $('#frame01').removeClass('hidden');
$('#frame02,#frame03,#frame04,#frame05').addClass('hidden');
                }else{
                    $('#frame01').addClass('hidden');
```

I don't know how you have yours set up, but removing the `href="#"` with this set up worked on mine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be tricky. I tested with this code:

```
<body>
Hallo
<br>
<div style="height:2000px; width:100px"></div>
<br />    
<a href="#" onclick="alert('click');return false;" 
            onmousedown="alert('down');return false;"
            onmouseup="alert('up');return false;"
            onmouseover="alert('over');return false;"
            onmouseout="alert('out');return false;">

click me</a>
</body>
```

What happens is, that when I refresh the page on iPhone and tap for the first time I get:

1. over
2. down
3. up
4. click
5. scroll up

Every next tap I get:

1. down
2. up
3. click
4. **No** scroll up

Funny enough, this works only, when the code contains the alerts. If no alerts inside code, scrolling up happens every time I tap....

For sure there's some magic with hrefs in mobile safari, which you can see, when you hold the link (without lifting the finger): An action sheet appears ("copy", "open", "open in ..." etc.) **before** one of the events is fired.

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried with

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false">click me</a>
```

and it works well

Answer (score 0):

Why not? I think, you must call a function and not only return false...

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction()" id="test_a">click me</a>

function myFunction() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('test_a');
  if (elem.addEventListener) {
      elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
          alert('clicked');
      }, false);
  } else {
      elem.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
          alert('clicked');
      });
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question, please ignore the js code before. Just html, but still doesn't work...

Comment: The `onclick` attribute expects JavaScript code rather than a URL. Thus `javascript:` is just redundant (though at least it won't throw a syntax error since it's valid code).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try this:

```
<a href="#" id='test'>click me</a>
```

in js:

```
$('a#test').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Secondly(if the first variant will not work):

```
<a href="#" id='test' onclick='return DummyFunction();'>click me</a>
```

in js:

```
function DummyFunction(){
    return false;
}
```

As far as i remember, one of these variant solved the same problem, when i had it.

The first variant is much better, becouse you don't mix html and javascript

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I went with a similar solution, but backed up a bit more with some conditional checking ... this is jQuery based and used for login in Sitefinity.

```
  if ($.browser.safari) {
    $('.sfSubmitBtn').attr('onclick', 'event.preventDefault(); return false;');
  }
```

I did find that using the event.preventDefault() *caused* a similar issues to begin occurring in some versions of IE.